# Sort nested list by second value

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

```
Input : [[0, 2], [1, 4], [2, 6]]
```

Description : I need to print two lists with greater value by comparing the element in the 2nd place.

```
Expected Output: [[1, 4], [2, 6]]
```

Comment: Use duplicate to sort - slice as many as you want (2) from sorted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sorted` and specify in the `key` argument that you want to sort each sublist by the second element using `operator.itemgetter`. Then slice the returned list to select the two last sublists:

```
l = [[0, 2], [1, 4], [2, 6]]

from operator import itemgetter
sorted(l, key=itemgetter(1))[-2:]
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 4], [2, 6]]
```

Comment: Thank You, It will work.

Comment: @yatu , can you explain how this works please

Comment: What is it that you'd like some explanation on @Navi ? They functionality of `key`? What itemgetter does?

Comment: itemgetter functionality

Comment: itemgetter is a simple way to fetch an item from its operand, a list in this case. Try doing for example `itemgetter(1)([1,2,3,4])`. This will return the second items in the list. Hope this helps... for more details read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html)

Comment: how to sort in ascending order?

Comment: Slice from the other end, [:2] @santosh

Comment: And check the docs, you can also specify `reverse` asan argument for sorted